# drive mounting problem

Tags: mount

I am new in ubuntu, I installed ubuntu with windows 7. I had three partitions in which one which was Fat32, and i formatted it from windows 7 to ntfs. Now when I start ubuntu I get this error at start up.

```
"**The disk drive for /windows is not ready yet or not present
Continue to wait; or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery**"
```

Here is my fstab file.

```
#/etc/fstab: static file system information.
#Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name                       
devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=8c6172f2-015e-43af-a587-e93f606b307c /               ext4            errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=82a8f81c-1deb-4610-9032-77139404f08d /boot           ext4        defaults        0       2
# /windows was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=8996-BA9F  /windows        vfat    utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=76cf4955-f0f7-4c5c-92ec-5af7ec133f1d none            swap    sw                  0       0
```

kindly can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should change vfat to ntfs in your fstab file.

And make sure you have an ntfs driver installed (e.g. ntfs-3g).

Comment: I made the changes, but I am still having the problem.

Comment: What happens if you try to mount the file manually:
`sudo mount /dev/sda8 /windows`

Comment: The problem is at time of installation of ubuntu i made this partition in Fat32 and assigned /windows to it, but then i wanted to change it into ntfs, i did it from windows 7, then from ubuntu i split the partition to 2 partitions since it was too big and i wanted 2 separate partitions for my work. now at ubuntu startup it says that ubuntu cannot mount /windows.

Comment: Please paste the output from the following command: `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes

Comment: 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors

Comment: Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Comment: Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Comment: I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Comment: Disk identifier: 0x0002621c

Comment: Device     Boot          Start            End         Blocks      Id      System

Comment: /dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: /dev/sda2          206848   204802047   102297600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: /dev/sda2          206848   204802047   102297600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Comment: /dev/sda5       204804096   263395327    29295616   83  Linux

Comment: /dev/sda6       263397376   271208447     3905536   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: /dev/sda7       271210496   273162239      975872   83  Linux

Comment: /dev/sda8       273164288   580364287   153600000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: /dev/sda9       580366336   976771071   198202368    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT